# How to update a window in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlabel

Im working on a simple project in QtCreator where you input text into a line_edit which then gets printed after clicking a button. It works but I need to resize the window in order to see the updated/changed display.

So starting off with the main.cpp, I have left it as default after some tests:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

That has the issue I was talking about above. I decided to add `w.update();` and see if that fixed the issue, it did not. I thought maybe it was because the program was not looping, so I entered the code in a while(true) loop which also was to no avail.

The mainwindow.cpp file is as follows:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->textBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(setText()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::setText()
{
    QString temp = ui->inputText->text();
    ui->displayLabel->setText(temp);

}
```

MainWindow.hpp:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void setText();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Is there a QObject or predifined function in QT that allows me to update the window or automatically updates the window after a detected user change?

Edit: The UI file might be of importance as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>554</width>
    <height>463</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="displayLabel">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>140</x>
      <y>150</y>
      <width>251</width>
      <height>91</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="scaledContents">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="wordWrap">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>130</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>251</width>
      <height>81</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="inputText"/>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="textBtn">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Display Text</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>554</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image]

Comment: The function update () does not work for that, nor does the magic (you have read the docs), using while True is a GUI is the worst thing you can do. On the other hand if you do not provide a [mcve] we can not help since your question currently falls on the off-topic: *"why isn't this code working?"*

Comment: My bad, apologies. I have updated the question so now you can read the code and understand the program. I have also changed the question so now instead of asking "why isnt this working", its become more of "what can I do or what should I do in place of this". Thanks

Comment: I see that you have made the changes and now your question is of quality, so I removed my downvote, so you do not have this kind of problems related to the format of your question I recommend reading [ask] and passing the [tour], for another On the other hand, I recommend you mark it as correct if any answer helps you solve your problem, I say this because in a previous question you indicate that the answer helped you but you have not marked it as correct.

Comment: thanks for the help. I am relatively new to QT and Stack Overflow. Will check out the 'how to ask' and the 'tour'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the update of the GUI but the `QLabel` does not change size, the initial size depends on the initial text, and if you set a text with larger size only part of the text will be displayed. To adjust the size of the label to the size of the text you must use [`adjustSize()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#adjustSize):

```
void MainWindow::setText()
{
    QString temp = ui->inputText->text();
    ui->displayLabel->setText(temp);
    ui->displayLabel->adjustSize();
}
```

On the other hand in Qt5 it is advisable to use the new connection syntax since they have several advantages as indicated by [the docs](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), in your case you must change your code to:

```
connect(ui->textBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::setText);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the solution. I've added that to my code as is but the displayLabel still does not update with the new text until after I resize the window.

Comment: @INeedHelpFrequently What do you expect to happen when you change the size of the window ?, You could also share your .ui file

Comment: @INeedHelpFrequently Maybe an image would help you understand your problem.

Comment: I don't expect anything to change when I resize the window. I just expect the display label to update after clicking the button. However, the displayLabel only updates if I resize the window, not automatically. I have to resize the window every time I update the displayLabel. I have also added my UI file.

Comment: @INeedHelpFrequently since you have shown your .ui I think you understand your problem, I see that when the text is very long the window does not have enough width to show all the text what do you want to happen with the window? Do you want the width to increase?

Comment: I thought the displayLabel would wrap the text because I checked that option in the design editor. If the window's width needs to increase to incorporate the text, then I would want the width to increase to fit the text. However, even small words like "hello"(which fit well inside the window's default size) don't seem to show up unless I resize the window by a pixel.

Comment: @INeedHelpFrequently You could show an image of the output you get when using the word "Hello" because I find it strange that you have a problem with this text. I get https://imgur.com/a/GYBHM8l

Comment: Here is a gif that I think shows my problem well. The displayLabel does not resize in relation to the window and it does not update unless I resize the window. Here is the gif(~0:15): https://gph.is/2QPYdgq

Comment: @INeedHelpFrequently What version of Qt do you have? It seems to me that your version has a bug, report it: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/bughowto.html

Comment: I'm using QT Creator version 4.7.0 based on QT 5.11.1 (Clang 8.0 (Apple), 64 Bit). It was built on July 17, 2018.

Comment: @INeedHelpFrequently Update to Qt 5.11.2 maybe it has been solved, if it has not been solved then report it, it has all aspect of a bug, also points out in your question your OS.

Comment: I'm thinking of switching over to linux/windows for continued c++ development especially with QT because it seems windows is the better OS for this type of development. I also plan to learn the windows API in the future after getting comfortable with gui programming with QT.

Comment: @INeedHelpFrequently I use linux, and an old windows user tells you, Linux for development environments is the easiest. :-)